# How see on display minute and second CurrentTime <video> in html5 if use jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I want see on display CurrentTime minute and second video.

```
var id = $('#main_video_player');

alert(id.get(0).currentTime); //worked i see '12.324543356'

var minnow=id.get(0).currentTime.split('.')[0];   
alert(minnow); //not worked

var secnow=id.get(0).currentTime.split('.')[1].substr('0','1');   
alert(secnow); //not worked
```

**Thanks all for help=)**

**Right code for show seconds:**

```
alert(time.toString().split('.')[0]);
```

**Code down for show correct time in hours, minute an second:**

```
var id = $('#video');

timenow=id.get(0).currentTime;

if (parseInt(timenow)/60>=1) {
        var h = Math.floor(timenow / 3600);
        timenow = timenow - h * 3600;               
        var m = Math.floor(timenow / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(timenow % 60);
        if(h.toString().length<2){h='0'+h;}
        if(m.toString().length<2){m='0'+m;}
        if(s.toString().length<2){s='0'+s;}
        alert(h+' : '+m+' : '+s);          
    } else {
        var m = Math.floor(timenow / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(timenow % 60);
        if(m.toString().length<2){m='0'+m;}
        if(s.toString().length<2){s='0'+s;}
        alert(m+' : '+s);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `currentTime` to a `String` to perform `.split()` and `.substr()` on it, e.g.

```
var time = id.get(0).currentTime;
var minutes = time.toString().split('.')[0];   
var seconds = time.toString().split('.')[1].substr('0','1');
```

To convert them back to a `float` (Number) for use with numerical functions do like so:

```
minutes = parseFloat(minutes);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/NpgD5/23/ for a working example (click on the video to get the time).

**EDIT:** `currentTime` returns the time in seconds so your `minnow` variable is actually seconds and `secnow` are milliseconds, a better way of getting minutes and seconds from `currentTime` is:

```
var time = id.get(0).currentTime;
var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);   
var seconds = Math.floor(time);
```

Comment: @Strannik No problem, but note that what you currently have as minutes in your code is actually seconds in the video.

Comment: @Strannik updated with how to get correct seconds and minutes more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can Code like that:

```
var id = $('#main_video_player');
var idn = 'VideoBar_wrap';

alert(id.get(0).currentTime); //worked i see '12.324543356'

var minnow=String(id.get(0).currentTime).split('.')[0];   
alert(minnow);

var secnow=String(String(id.get(0).currentTime).split('.')[1]).substr(0,1);   
alert(secnow);
```

**You have to convert currentTime value to String object**