# HTML5 video showing time in Javascript - especially seconds

Tags: javascript, html, video

I would like to ask for the best way to show HTML5 video time in Javascript. I can count hours, minutes and seconds in Javascript, BUT!!! The seconds are shown sometimes faster, sometimes slower, depending on firing video.ontimeupdate event. I want to show the video time correctly every second. In other words - I want to reach showing the time every second exactly every second, not like 0:00:01 is displayed one and half second and 0:00:02 one second, then 0:00:03 half second and then 0:00:04 one second and so on. Just randomly. Is there some way to show seconds exactly as seconds, or it is unachievable behavior?

EDIT: OK, I post my code, but I don't thing it will be more clear. I asked showing the time every second of the video time correctly, not some second is faster and some is slower. I know there is a function setInterval, but it has nothing to do with video time. Here is the code:

```
var time=window.document.getElementById('time'); //time is element <div id="time"></div> showing the time
var st; //show time
video.ontimeupdate=function(){
  ct=parseInt(video.currentTime); //ct is current time
  if(st!=ct) //little effort to optimize processing and showing the time
  {
    st=ct;
    var hours=parseInt(st/3600);
    var minutes=parseInt((st%3600)/60);
    var seconds=parseInt(st%60);
    if((''+minutes).length==1)minutes='0'+minutes;
    if((''+seconds).length==1)seconds='0'+seconds;
    time.innerHTML=''+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
  }
};
```

I think the code is correct, but there is some irregularity in firing ontimeupdate event. Perhaps I have some solution - if the play button is pressed, then use setInterval to show time exactly every second, if pause or stop pressed - clearInterval(intervalId). I'll appreciate if someone has more precise solution.

Comment: can you show the code you have tried so we can comment on that

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915018/how-see-on-display-minute-and-second-currenttime-video-in-html5-if-use-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have any code to go off of so I can't really answer the question. From what you said you have the code, but having issues with it displaying the time right.

I also do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, because HTML5 has a standard video tag (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp))

This shows the seconds etc.

Now to display a timer (this is for demo purposes only really not relevant but thought it could help)

```
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Since I have zero code to go by - I also would reccomend this:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/

Good luck if you edit and post code I may be able to understand more thanks!